# Linearly independent subset and basis

Tags: linear-algebra

The theorem I'm studying is the following.

> If W is a subspace of a finite dimensional vector space V, every linearly independemt subset of W is finite and **is part of a (finite) basis for W.**

The proof implicitly tells that the linearly independent subset S is in a basis of W. This is the part that I don't get it with the bolded part on the Theorem above. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: it means to say that any linearly independent subset of $W$ can be extended to a basis of $W$.

Comment: By "don't get it", are you saying that you don't understand what the bolded part of the theorem is asserting, or that you don't understand why it's true?

Comment: @GregMartin I am not sure what it is asserting.

Answer (score 1):

First, we have to think about what a linearly independent subset of $W$ would be. Let $dim(W)=m$. We can start by pulling out a single vector $w_1$ from $W$. The set $\{w_1\}$ will always be linearly independent. Now we can pick another vector, $w_2$ from $W$ so that $\{w_1,w_2\}$ is linearly independent. If we continue this process, we will eventually get to the $m^{th}$ vector and will have a linearly independent set $\{w_1,...,w_m\}$. This, by definition, is a basis of $W$.

From here, it is impossible to find a $(m+1)^{th}$ vector that will keep the set linearly independent. So, "every linearly independent subset of $W$" will have at most $dim(W)$ vectors. It will either be the case that this subset **is** a basis for $W$, or it **is part of a basis for $W$** (and can be further expanded to get a basis).